# No matching distribution found for django

Tags: python, django, pip

I'm quite fresh in programming - I was using Django 1.10.6 and I tried to switch to 1.18 and that's what happened:

```
    (env)$ pip install django==1.18
    Collecting django==1.18
    Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django==1.18 
    (from versions: 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.2.4, 1.2.5, 1.2.6, 
    1.2.7, 1.3, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 1.3.6, 1.3.7, 1.4, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 
    1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.4.5, 1.4.6, 1.4.7, 1.4.8, 1.4.9, 1.4.10, 1.4.11, 1.4.12, 1.4.13, 
    1.4.14, 1.4.15, 1.4.16, 1.4.17, 1.4.18, 1.4.19, 1.4.20, 1.4.21, 1.4.22, 1.5, 
    1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.5.5, 1.5.6, 1.5.7, 1.5.8, 1.5.9, 1.5.10, 1.5.11, 
    1.5.12, 1.6, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.5, 1.6.6, 1.6.7, 1.6.8, 1.6.9, 
    1.6.10, 1.6.11, 1.7, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.7.4, 1.7.5, 1.7.6, 1.7.7, 1.7.8, 
    1.7.9, 1.7.10, 1.7.11, 1.8a1, 1.8b1, 1.8b2, 1.8rc1, 1.8, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 
    1.8.4, 1.8.5, 1.8.6, 1.8.7, 1.8.8, 1.8.9, 1.8.10, 1.8.11, 1.8.12, 1.8.13, 
    1.8.14, 1.8.15, 1.8.16, 1.8.17, 1.8.18, 1.9a1, 1.9b1, 1.9rc1, 1.9rc2, 1.9, 
    1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.9.4, 1.9.5, 1.9.6, 1.9.7, 1.9.8, 1.9.9, 1.9.10, 1.9.11, 
    1.9.12, 1.9.13, 1.10a1, 1.10b1, 1.10rc1, 1.10, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.3, 1.10.4, 
    1.10.5, 1.10.6, 1.10.7, 1.11a1, 1.11b1, 1.11rc1, 1.11, 1.11.1, 1.11.2)
    No matching distribution found for django==1.18
```

What is wrong? I should upgrade pip?

Comment: Django's latest release is 1.11.2 Just `pip install django`

Comment: even on the list can you see anything like 1.18? or do you mean 1.8?

Comment: Please look at the release notes to see the available Django versions: https://www.djangoproject.com/download/

Comment: may be your python version doesn't have support for that specific version, if then, please upgrade python version and try it again

Comment: In my case the Django website said to install "2.1.5", and I got this error - turns out I since I'm using Python 2.7, the version I really want is 1.11 apparently.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As stated on your error message, all compatible django versions are listed there. There is no 1.18 version for django.

The latest compatible django release will be installed if you type `pip install django`.

If you want to install other version, make sure you have the correct version and use `pip install django==1.x`

EDIT: As stated by **Peterino** on a **comment** below, by running `pip install django` you're installing the latest **compatible** version and this may not be the latest one. To install the latest version you *may* be required to install/update Python to a newer release

Comment: Thanks! I was asked to install this version, so I assumed it is an existing one. Next time I will check by myself!

Comment: yea, it was probably a typo haha, glad I could help, good luck.

Comment: Not quite all Django versions will be listed here. Up to the latest LTS version (3.2) will be listed. There are new Django versions (currently 4.0) that are not yet listed here.

Comment: *Watch out! This is tricky.* – Current Django versions (4.0+) **need Python 3.8+** to run and be installed. When you use a Python version lower that that to run `pip install` (on your local machine) then only compatible versions will be listed. *Example:* Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has Python 3.6 installed by default, hence only Django version <4.0 will listed! You have to use a newer Python version to fix the problem and successfully install Django 4.0+. (If you use `tox` you can use the `basepython` setting in `tox.ini` to override the Python version.)

Answer (score 7):

You try to install a version of Django **that does not exists**.

If you want the latest version :

```
pip install --upgrade django
```

You can find all versions available on pipy : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Django

Comment: Thanks a lot - I was asked to install this version, probably a typo, but I assumed it was an existing version

Comment: Take note the latest for Python2.7 and Python3 are different. Better use a virtualenv created with the correct Python version

Comment: According to initial post error, he was using virtual environment.